# Rails: Creating an HTML Snippet with a Variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a submit button that is a block of HTML code because of styling and images to make it look better. (I stole most of it from Wufoo).

This is one every form in the application and I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this. Something like a partial or helper?

The name of the button "Submit" or "Add Contact" needs to be a variable.

## snippet

[image] Add Contact  #variable text 
    
        [image] Back
    
    
* Required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a application-wide helper for this.  Helpers are modules containing methods that are shared by multiple views.  You can easily define your own helper that works like the ['submit_tag' helper method](http://rails.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) that generates the button.

Answer (score 2):

consider partials (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something partials were invented for.